# How many passes does it take to join 2 relations of fixed size with M buffer blocks?

Tags: database-theory, relational-algebra

So let's say 2 relations, B(R) = 200,000 and B(S) = 300,000. The memory buffer is M = 400 blocks.

How many passes would this take to join?

Notation:

[image]

Comment: What does your notation mean?  What is meant by "B(R)"?  What are your thoughts?  Where did you get stuck, when trying to solve this yourself?  We're happy to help you understand concepts, but just solving an exercise-style problem for you is unlikely to achieve that.

Comment: @D.W. I added the notation to the question

Comment: 1. Don't use images as primary content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources.  Thank you!  2. We still want you to make an effort on your own before asking here and to show us what progress you've made and where you got stuck, rather than just asking us to solve the exercise for you.

Comment: @D.W. It's standard notation from what I see. I just grabbed those definitions out of a random PDF on a Google search.